# java program for read an excel file using Apache POI and eclipse as editor

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-poi

I have created this code to read an excel file which contain boolean, string and numeric values using APACHE POI.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;



public class ExcelRead {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File excel = new File ("C:\\Users\\...\\Documents\\test.xls");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);

    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
    HSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheet("Input");

    int rowNum = ws.getLastRowNum()+1;
    int colNum = ws.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
    String[][] data = new String[rowNum][colNum];


    for (int i=0; i<rowNum; i++){
        HSSFRow row = ws.getRow(i);
            for (int j=0; j<colNum; j++){
                HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);
                String value = cellToString(cell);
                data[i][j] = value;
                System.out.println("The value is" + value);

            }
       }
    }

public static String cellToString (HSSFCell cell){

int type;
Object result;
type = cell.getCellType();

     switch(type) {


    case 0://numeric value in excel
        result = cell.getNumericCellValue();
        break;
    case 1: //string value in excel
        result = cell.getStringCellValue();
        break;
    case 2: //boolean value in excel
        result = cell.getBooleanCellValue ();
        break;
    default:
        throw new RunTimeException("There are no support for this type of 
                                                cell");                      
}

return result.toString();


}
```

When I run it using eclipse I get this warning:

> Usage: AddDimensionedImage imageFile outputFile

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Maybe you are throwing throwable exception not the base exception
Try with java.lang the base exception

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to run a different project/class named "AddDimensionedImage".

Right click on your ExcelRead file on Eclipse and choose Run As -> Java Application

Comment: you junst need to select your project name not any thing else